# xUnit - How to pass (string, string) to InlineData

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

Title is pretty self explanatory. How do I pass `(string, string)` to inline data?

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Xunit;

namespace Summer_Outfit.UnitTesting;

public class OutfitTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Execute_DegreesTimeFromDay_ReturnsOutfitShoes()
    {
        // Arrange
        const int degrees = 20;
        const string timeFromDay = "Morning";
        var outfit = new Outfit();
        var expected = ("Shirt", "Moccasins");

        // Act
        var actual = outfit.Execute(degrees, timeFromDay);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
    
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(20, "Morning", ("Shirt", "Moccasins"))] // compile-time error here
    [InlineData(20, "Afternoon", ("Shirt", "Moccasins"))] // compile-time error here
    [InlineData(20, "Evening", ("Shirt", "Moccasins"))] // compile-time error here
    public void Execute_MultipleDegreesTimeFromDay_ReturnsOutfitShoes(int degrees, string timeFromDay, (string, string)expected)
    {
        // Arrange
        var outfit = new Outfit();

        // Act
        var actual = outfit.Execute(degrees, timeFromDay);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just specify the two parts separately (as two method parameters), and combine them within the method? I suspect that will be the simplest solution.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I would like to know how it works with passing them at once

Comment: I suspect it may not even be possible, and I definitely don't have time to do the research on that. I would really suggest just using separate parameters and moving on.

Comment: as you already figured out, it wont.

Comment: @JonSkeet, in that case, I would do that. Thanks

Comment: I'd guess it isn't possible. [The language specification (section 21.2.4)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes) has some constraints on parameters that can be passed to attributes, and it does not include `ValueTuple` which is what a `(string, string)` evaluates to (as far as I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the language specification section given by @JoshuaRobinson in the comment:

21.2.4 Attribute parameter types
The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:

One of the following types: `bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort`.

The type `object`.

The type `System.Type`.

Enum types.

Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.

A constructor argument or public field that does not have one of these types, shall not be used as a positional or named parameter in an attribute specification.

So if you didn't want to make them separate parameters in your method, as a different workaround you could use an array:

```
[InlineData(20, "Morning", new string[] {"Shirt", "Moccasins"})]
public void Execute_MultipleDegreesTimeFromDay_ReturnsOutfitShoes(int degrees, string timeFromDay, string[] expected)
```

You'd still have to make a tuple out of it for the comparison, however:

```
Assert.Equal((expected[0], expected[1]), actual);
```

If you want to keep it as a tuple, you can use a `MemberData` or `ClassData` data source. See https://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/ for examples.